# How to dockerize .net project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

There is an application that is divided into layers. The application consists of several layers, which are the console type and, most importantly, the web application entry point type. I want to put this application, this API into a docker container.

[image]

In the .API I have Dockerfile, which consists of code like this:

```yaml
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    
    COPY ["/ShoppingCart.API.csproj", "ShoppingCart.API/"]
    COPY ["./ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/"]
    #COPY ["ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces/ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces/"]
    #COPY ["ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data/ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data/"]
    #COPY ["ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Business/ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Business.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Businesss/"]
    #COPY ["ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces/ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces/"]
    
    RUN dotnet restore "ShoppingCart.API/ShoppingCart.API.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/ShoppingCart.API"
    RUN dotnet build "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
    
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
    
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingCart.API.dll"]
```

But the line

```
COPY ["./ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/"]
```

Doesn't want to search the source, probably, I'm missing something special. or maybe there is some other way?

Comment: What do you mean by `Doesn't want to search the source`? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @mamen Yes, each time when i run docker-compose i'm getting error: "file not found in build context" and shows the path of that path

Comment: @A.Laketych:  add your docker compose code also